# Sorting algorithm timing discrepancies between g++ and Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, visual-studio-2012, g++

So I have implemented a heap, merge, and quicksort. I time the three sorts all the same way.

```
double DiffClocks(clock_t clock1, clock_t clock2){
    double diffticks = clock1 - clock2;
    double diffsecs = diffticks / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    return diffsecs;
}
```

Then with each sort, I time them the same way. Just repeated for each different sort.

```
void heapsort(int myArray[], int n){
    clock_t begin, end;
    begin = clock();
    heapSortMain(myArray, n);
    end = clock();
    double elapsedTime = heapDiffClocks(end, begin);
    std::cout << '\t' << elapsedTime;
}
```

All three of the sorts are working. I have a function that verifies the arrays are sorted after executing each sort. My question is, why do I have such a big difference between the timing when running on g++ and on Visual Studio?

My output from Visual Studio 2012:

```
n     Heap  Merge   Quick
100      0      0       0
1000     0      0       0
10000    0.01   0       0
100000   0.14   0.02    0.03
1000000  1.787  0.22    0.33
10000000 24.116 2.475   6.956
```

My output from g++ 4.7.2

```
n     Heap  Merge   Quick
100      0      0       0
1000     0      0       0
10000    0      0       0.01
100000   0.05   0.02    0.02
1000000  0.59   0.33    0.29
10000000 10.78  3.79    3.3
```

I used a standard `bubbleDown` and swap implementation with heap. A recursive mergesort with a merge to merge the two sorted subarrays. A recursive quicksort with a median of 3 pivot and partition function.

I have always understood quicksort to be the fastest general sorting algorithm. On VS it really lags behind merge, and heap just goes up quickly when I hit 10 million on VS.

Comment: Without 1) Source code for your code, 2) exact compiler options used, it's pretty hard to say what the difference may be.

Comment: Did you use debug or release version while compiling on VS? Debug version might have an overhead of maintaining debug information, and not being optimized as release version would.

Comment: I used the debug version while compiling on VS.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I can post the code for the sorts, if that will help. I just didn't want to post a wall of code.

Comment: @kemotoe That may be a factor in the timing discrepancies that you saw. Re-compile as release, and time it again.

Comment: Whenever benchmarking, make sure you enable at least MOST of the optimisation (so release build and -O2 for gcc).

Comment: A vanilla quick-sort is actually comparatively slow! You need to pull quite a few tricks to get it fast. The result is a hybrid algorithm using quick-sort until either Introsort determines that it is handling a bad case and it needs to switch to something else (e.g., mergesort or heapsort) or the ranges are small where it switches to insertion-sort. You might want to compare against `std::sort()` to see the effect...

Comment: @kemotoe - For VS, do a release build. Are you sorting 32 bit integers, 64 bit integers, ???. Using VS release build, on my system, Intel 2600K 3.4 ghz, the time to sort 10,000,000 pseudo random unsigned 32 bit integers for top down merge sort is 0.94 seconds, for bottom up merge sort, 0.89 seconds, for quicksort choosing middle value for pivot 0.78 seconds. Median of 3 pivot would take longer.

Comment: @kemotoe - quicksort using median of 3 took 0.80 seconds. In X86 / 64 bit mode with 16 registers, most of them used as pointers, a 4 way bottom up merge sort took 0.80 seconds, the same as quicksort with median of 3.